# Weird things are happening when connecting my Android phone via USB

Tags: android, eclipse, usb

so I'm developing for Android and am trying to run some applications on my phone instead of with the emulator. I'm running Windows XP (woot) and have the Motorola Droid RAZR M. When I connect my phone to the computer it first of all kills my internet connection so that the computer cannot see any available networks. Also, the computer will not recognize the phone unless USB Debugging is turned off, so how am I supposed to test apps without that!

When the USB Debugging option is off everything is fine and dandy and the computer sees it as a media device, however when USB debugging is on it ceases to think of it as the same phone and tries to search for new hardware. So do I need to download a different USB driver?

Comment: As this concerns development setup, it actually is on topic for SO rather than for a user forum such as Android.stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

It may be because the phone is mounted in tethering mode, the computer thinks the phone is an internet source. Check your settings under Wireless and Network!

Comment: Nope, yeah I thought that at first and have tried countless combinations.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to download the exact driver for my phone, I have a Galaxy Nexus. I was able to find this link from the manufacturer that should work for your phone, but you may have already  tried it.

https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481